# How to confirm RabbitMQ messages with Java?

Tags: java, queue, rabbitmq, client, confirmation

I tried to figure out how to confirm messages in java but I haven't understood it.
Here is the official RabbitMQ example:
http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-java-client/file/default/test/src/com/rabbitmq/examples/ConfirmDontLoseMessages.java

The problem is that they use 10000 messages to send to an queue and only after that they wait when all messages will be confirmed. I need to send 1 message and only one message per thread and confirm it (In my case I have several equal publishers that have to send messages from time to time). How to confirm one message (not confirm all messages)?

I need something like:

```
for (long i = 0; i < MSG_COUNT; ++i) {
    ch.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME,
                   MessageProperties.PERSISTENT_BASIC,
                   "nop".getBytes());
    ch.wait_for_confirm();
    if(ch.isConfirmed){
        //OK
    }
    else{
        //Republish
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this post:

http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/02/10/introducing-publisher-confirms/

In short you can use the `tx-transactions`:

`ch.txSelect();
for (int i = 0; i < MSG_COUNT; ++i) {
        ch.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME,
                            MessageProperties.PERSISTENT_BASIC,
                            "nop".getBytes());
        ch.txCommit();
}`

or the `publish-confirmation` handler:

`ch.addConfirmListener(new ConfirmListener() {....}`

The first one is easier but slower than the second one.

Comment: There is the waitForConfirms() method: [link](https://rabbitmq.github.io/rabbitmq-java-client/api/current/com/rabbitmq/client/Channel.html#waitForConfirms())  Note, you have to set the channel to "confirm mode": channel.confirmSelect()

Answer (score 0):

You should need to use Acknowledgement for each message you can check the below link :
https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback #Sam Onela